# clean install ubuntu 14.04 erased all win7 partitions, how to recover with testdisk?

Tags: 14.04, data-recovery, testdisk

am totally new to linux, recently i have installed ubuntu 14.04 on my windows 7 professional desktop, on windows i had 3 partitions (except windows partition) while installation i had not selected any partition to install ubuntu 14.04, while in ubuntu installation i only selected replace windows option and not selected any partition selection options. after installation my desk top has only one hard disk with space of 160 gb. disk showing 5 swap partitions. So, i read and used testdisk to recover erased partitions while running testdisk some problems are facing, attached screen shot.

So, Kindly help me how to use testdisk to recover 3 partitions step by step, what are the requirements to use testdisk, and how to recover successfully without errors.

Thanks in advance,

Tell me next step form here, what to select and what to do ?

from above screen by pressing enter to continue, below screen appear. from this again next step to do ?

Regards
Raju B

Comment: For your "disk too small" issue see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/400150/how-to-resolve-the-harddisk-seems-too-small-with-testdisk-deeper-search

Answer (score 1):

I too faced same problem when installed ubuntu. I thought i lost my 500GB data but finally able to recover it using testdisk. See the link below for recovery:-

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step

Hope it will help you.

Comment: am doing step by step as cgsecurity.org.wiki but finally getting error as "The hard disk (160gb/149 gib) seem too small (< 3339 gb /3110 gib). check the hard disk size : HD jumpers settings, BIOS detection....